# React Hooks State with preserving previous state (REACT DND)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dnd

I am trying dynamic setState using `useState` to an object.

```
const [check, setcheck] = useState({
    q1:'',
    q2:''
})
```

but I am failing to preserve the last state. I am using react dnd whenever I start dragging, it clear "State". I am not sure if its rendering or what or I am doing something wrong.
I have an option to set the state to localStorage but Can someOne please review my code block I will be thankful.

following is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";
import ItemTypes from "./ItemTypes";
const style = {..}
const ItemBox = ({ url, id, idref }) => {
  const [check, setcheck] = useState({
    q1: "",
    q2: ""
  });

  console.log(check, "CheckState");
  useEffect(() => {
    idref.current = { check };
  }, [check, idref]);
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { id, type: ItemTypes.BOX },
    end: (item, monitor) => {
      const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult();
      if (item && dropResult) {

        // * here I am trying to set the state *

        setcheck({ ...check, [item.id]: dropResult.id });
      }
    },
    collect: monitor => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    })
  });

  const opacity = isDragging ? 0.4 : 1;
  return (
    <div
      id={id}
      ref={drag}
      style={{ ...style, opacity, backgroundImage: `url(${url})` }}
    />
  );
};
export default ItemBox;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the callback version of the `setcheck` becuase `useDrag` caches the options you pass so `check` refers to the first time `check`.

```
setcheck((currentCheck) => ({ ...currentCheck, [item.id]: dropResult.id }));
```

Comment: I already tried this one sadly not working with dragEvent .. it clears state and starts with initial one as soon I start dragging an item.. it might be related to reactDND ??

Comment: @RebelCoder when you drop an item do you move it to another container (*in terms of where the node is rendered in t he DOM?*)